# Reading from file does not work as expected with fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have this file:

```
0 -> 1:50 2:30 3:10
1 ->
2 -> 0:10 3:20
3 -> 1:20 2:10 3:30
```

And I want to extract all the numbers from the file with this code:

```
int a, b, c;
while (fscanf(fp, "%d ->", &a) == 1) {
    printf("%d ->", a);
    while (fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &b, &c) == 2) {
        printf(" %d:%d", b, c);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The idea is that on the first loop it will scan the first number followed by space followed by -> and then the inner loop will scan the following sequence of " %d:%d" until the end of line which will then make the outer loop return 1 because it could successfully read "%d ->".

Ouput of code:

```
0 -> 1:50 2:30 3:10
```

It seems like it doesn't work as expected, and the outer while loop exits when it tried to read the number 1 from the second line(but it should?). I just find this weird because I've done something similar recently and it was working fine.

After removing the loops and replacing with this code I get the correct results so it had something to do with my loops:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d ->", &a);
fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &b, &c);
fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &b, &c);
fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &b, &c);
fscanf(fp, "%d ->", &a);
fscanf(fp, "%d ->", &a);
fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &b, &c);
fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &b, &c);
fscanf(fp, "%d ->", &a);
fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &b, &c);
fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &b, &c);
fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &b, &c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iteration of `while (fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &b, &c) == 2) {` is consuming the `"\n1"` in `"\n1 ->"`.  This fouls the following `fscanf(fp, "%d ->", &a)`, which starts at `" ->"` and stops the loop.

Code needs to detect the `'\n'`.  format directives/specifiers like `" "` and `"%d"` consume end-of-line without reporting that.

---

Direct solution: As the file is *lines* of data, then read *lines* of text with `fgets()`.

Use `"%n"` to record offset of scan.

```
// Generous maximum line size
#define LINE_N 1024

char line[LINE_N];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
  int a;
  int n = 0;
  //                 v--- space needed to consume trailing whitespace
  sscanf(line, "%d -> %n", &a, &n) == 1) {
  if (n == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid line '%s'\n", line);
    continue;
  }
  printf("%d ->", a);
  char *p = line + n; 
  while (*p) {
    int b,c;
    n = 0;
    //              v--- space needed to consume trailing whitespace
    sscanf(p, "%d:%d %n", &b, &c, &n);
    if (n == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Invalid rest of line '%s'\n", p);
      break;
    }
    printf(" %d:%d", b, c);
    p += n;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You are correct, I just tested it and it does indeed consume the 1 from the second line..I just thought that because it didn't match everything it would put it back into the stream.

Comment: @AristosGeorgiou `*scanf()` returns the number of specifiers successfully scanned which could be 2 or 1.  Or `EOF`  or 0 when no specifiers matched. 
 Research the function for detail on this case.  Further `"%d ->"` returning 1 only means an `int` was scanned.  It does not mean the `int` was certainly followed by  `" ->"`.  That is why this code uses `'%n"`: to determine if scanning reached that point.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm isn't handling the newlines.  So it gets stuck and the end of the first line and isn't able to read anything matching `n ->`.

One way that works reliably for all C RTL implementations is to use `fgets()` to read each whole line (including the newline at the end) and then use `sscanf()` to parse the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to fseek one char ( newline ) at the last printf.